# get informations in a json object

Tags: jquery, json

I have this json object :

```
[
{
    "debut": "08-12-2014",
    "fin": "09-12-2014",
    "date_inconnue": "",
    "client_desactive": "0",
    "numero_info_fact": "0"
},
{
    "groupe_1": {
        "infos": {
            "commandes_id": "95",
            "groupes_id": "143",
            "lieu_depart": "Delta",
            "lieu_arrivee": "Brugges",
            "heure_depart": "9:00",
            "heure_arrivee": "13:00",
            "id": "143",
            "nom": "Nijs",
            "taille": "4"
        },
        "langues": [
            {
                "groupes_id": "143",
                "langues_id": "2",
                "id": "2",
                "langue": "Néerlandais",
                "statut": "0"
            }
        ],
        "langues_guide": [
            {
                "guides_id": "3",
                "langues_id": "1"
            },
            {
                "guides_id": "3",
                "langues_id": "2"
            },
            {
                "guides_id": "3",
                "langues_id": "3"
            }
        ],
        "activites": [],
        "fournisseurs": [
            {
                "groupes_id": "143",
                "fournisseurs_id": "15",
                "prix_achat": null,
                "prix_vente": null,
                "paye_par_bb": "1",
                "remarque": "",
                "id": "15",
                "nom": "Cars Dessaintes",
                "types_fournisseurs_id": "3",
                "tel": "02 355 89 87",
                "fax": "",
                "adresse": "Chaussée de Tubize",
                "cpostal": "1480",
                "commune": "Saintes",
                "fournisseurs_cat": [
                    {
                        "id": "15",
                        "nom": "Cars Dessaintes",
                        "types_fournisseurs_id": "3",
                        "tel": "02 355 89 87",
                        "fax": "",
                        "adresse": "Chaussée de Tubize",
                        "cpostal": "1480",
                        "commune": "Saintes"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "nom": "Cars Rent",
                        "types_fournisseurs_id": "3",
                        "tel": "0474 74 74 74",
                        "fax": "0474 75 75 75",
                        "adresse": "Rue Lambin 52",
                        "cpostal": "1050",
                        "commune": "Ixelles"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "guides": [
            {
                "guides_id": "3",
                "nom": "Kiss",
                "prenom": "Robert",
                "remarque": "",
                "id": "756",
                "prestations": [
                    {
                        "id": "60",
                        "nom": "Brel",
                        "types_activites_id": "1",
                        "remarque": "Quel bon guide..."
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "contacts": [
            {
                "id": "41",
                "remarque_contact_groupe": "Ne me quitte pas",
                "telephone_contact_groupe": "03 888 77 78",
                "mail_contact_groupe": null,
                "prenom_contact_groupe": null,
                "nom_contact_groupe": "Jacques Brel",
                "gsm_contact_groupe": null,
                "groupe_id": "143"
            },
            {
                "id": "42",
                "remarque_contact_groupe": "Oh mon Dieu",
                "telephone_contact_groupe": "02 888 78 98",
                "gsm_contact_groupe": null,
                "groupe_id": "143"
            }
        ]
    },
    "groupe_2": {
        "infos": {
            "commandes_id": "95",
            "groupes_id": "147",
            "lieu_depart": "RTL HOUSE",
            "lieu_arrivee": "",
            "id": "147",
            "nom": "RTL",
            "taille": ""
        },
        "langues": [
            {
                "groupes_id": "147",
                "langues_id": "3",
                "id": "3",
                "langue": "Anglais",
                "statut": "0"
            }
        ],
        "langues_guide": [
            {
                "guides_id": "1",
                "langues_id": "1"
            },
            {
                "guides_id": "1",
                "langues_id": "3"
            }
        ],
        "activites": [],
        "fournisseurs": [],
        "guides": [
            {
                "guides_id": "1",
                "nom": "Mets",
                "prenom": "Anthony",
                "remarque": "rthdgfhgfh dgdgdsgf",
                "id": "757",
                "prestations": [
                    {
                        "id": "127",
                        "nom": "Bourgmestres",
                        "types_activites_id": "1",
                        "remarque": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "contacts": [
            {
                "id": "58",
                "remarque_contact_groupe": "La plus belle !!!",
                "telephone_contact_groupe": "",
                "mail_contact_groupe": null,
                "prenom_contact_groupe": null,
                "nom_contact_groupe": "Pandeville Sophie",
                "gsm_contact_groupe": null,
                "groupe_id": "147"
            }
        ]
    }
},**
[
    {
        "id": "646",
        "id_commande": "95",
        "id_guide": "3",
        "heures_supplementaires": "0",
        "paiement_sur_place": "1",
        "remarque": "",
        "payements": [],
        "factures": [],
        "ardoises": []
    },
    {
        "id": "647",
        "id_commande": "95",
        "id_guide": "1",
        "heures_supplementaires": "0",
        "paiement_sur_place": "1",
        "remarque": "",
        "payements": [],
        "factures": [],
        "ardoises": []
    }
],
[
    [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "titre": "0",
            "nom": "Cornette",
            "prenom": "Arielle",
            "fonction": "",
            "nom_societe": "",
            "status_id": "2",
            "langues_id": "1",
            "tva": "",
            "client_id": "0",
            "client_desactive": "0",
            "remarque": "RAF",
            "numero_info_fact": "0",
            "langue": "Français",
            "statut": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "rue": "rue de l'Abattoir#Près de la Mosquée#Grand Duplex",
            "numero": "4",
            "boite": "5",
            "cp": "1070",
            "ville": "Anderlecht",
            "mail": "arcornet@ulb.ac.be",
            "telephone": "02 676 78 78",
            "gsm": "0467 76 78 90",
            "fax": "02 650 59 59",
            "types_informations_contact_id": "1",
            "clients_id": "60",
            "pays_id": "1",
            "pays": "Belgique"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "7",
            "gsm_contact_client": "0467 76 78 90",
            "fax_contact_client": "02 650 59 59",
            "telephone_contact_client": "02 676 78 78",
            "mail_contact_client": "arcornet@ulb.ac.be",
            "prenom_contact_client": "Arielle",
            "nom_contact_client": "Cornette",
            "clients_id": "60",
            "remarque": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "gsm_contact_client": "0478 76 78 78",
            "fax_contact_client": "",
            "telephone_contact_client": "02 786 78 78",
            "mail_contact_client": "alice.boutboul@gmail.com",
            "prenom_contact_client": "Alice",
            "nom_contact_client": "Boutboul",
            "clients_id": "60",
            "remarque": "BELLE-FILLE"
        }
    ]
]
```

]

I would like to get those informations :

from

```
{
    "groupe_1": {
        "infos": {
to

"gsm_contact_groupe": null,
                "groupe_id": "147"
```

I tried several ways, but I'm not able to get this part of the json objet.

```
run_in_tree(retour[1]);

                function run_in_tree(obj)
                {
                   for (key in obj)
                   {

                         $("#info_groupes").after('Key => '+obj[key]);
                         $("#info_groupes").after("<br>");
                         if (typeof obj[key] == 'object') run_in_tree(obj[key]);
                   }
                }
```

I'm not able to get the information (key and value)

I have some difficulties when I have to browse a big json objet.

Comment: What is those `**` in your code? Did you tried to make it bold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, it looks like you have an array. Of which the 2nd object in that array appears to contain a property for each group.

So to iterate the groups, you would do this:

```
var groups = obj[1];// Get the 2nd object;

for(var key in groups){
    var group = groups[key];
    console.log(group.infos.commandes_id);
}
```

You can then use this same logic to iterate the properties of any of the sub-objects too. For example, if you want to log all the `infos` data:

```
for(var infoKey in group.infos){
    var info = group.infos[infoKey];
    console.log(infoKey + " = " + info);
}
```

and iterating the contacts array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < group.contacts.length; i++){
    var contact = group.contacts[i];
    console.log(contact.id);
}
```

When you are working with big JSON like this, it helps to remember the difference between an array `[]` and an object `{}`, as you will want to access them in different ways (as shown above).

Hope that helps you get where you are trying to be

Comment: Your code and explanations are perfect, thank you sir !